# React app returning null on element?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a react modal that renders sign-in and sign-up form.
And on the form, there is a button by id of modal-sign-in-submit-button.
When I do

```
document.getElementById('modal-sign-in-submit-button');
```

It returns a type error, saying that such element does not exist...

```
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
```

Is there a package or a workaround in making it to recognize the button being in the html?

This works fine on console, but when I try to access an element rendered by React in a different script, it does not find such element. (Probably due to it not being generated yet).

Below is the source for the part,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Modal from 'react-modal';

class SignInModalTrigger extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
    open: false
    };
    this.openModal = this.openModal.bind(this);
    this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this);    
  }

  openModal() {
    this.setState({open: true});
  }

  closeModal() {
    this.setState({open: false});
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <a className="navbar-items" onClick={this.openModal} href="#">Sign in</a>
        <Modal className="sign-in-modal" isOpen={this.state.open}>
          <h1 className="modal-title">Sign in</h1>
          <div className="modal-inner-form">
            <input className="modal-input" id="modal-sign-in-mail-input"     type="email" placeholder="Enter your email here"/>
            <br />
            <br />
            <input className="modal-input" id="modal-sign-in-password-input"     type="password" placeholder="Enter your password here" pattern="(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}"/>
            <br />
            <br />
            <button className="modal-button" id="modal-sign-in-submit-button">Submit</button>
            <br />
            <br />
            <button className="modal-button" onClick={this.closeModal}>Close</button>
          </div>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SignInModalTrigger;
```

Comment: you are not creating any button with the id 'submit-button'

Comment: Please provide TypeError you're talking about

Comment: @Davidlrnt Oh, I meant modal-sign-in-submit-button

Comment: @cyberskunk TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Yes, it was a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A noob question it was, but I found a solution in achieving what I wanted.
It's to create functions within the class itself, and then bind it to the constructor.

So something like,

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    open: false
  };
  this.openModal = this.openModal.bind(this);
  this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this);
  this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
}

submit() {
  const submit = document.getElementById('modal-sign-up-submit-button');
  const email  = document.getElementById('modal-sign-up-mail-input').value;
  const pass   = document.getElementById('modal-sign-up-password-input').value;
  const promise = firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
  promise.then(e => window.location.href="index.html");
  promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));

  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
    if(firebaseUser) {
      this.setState({open: false});
      console.log("hi");
    }
  });
}

render() {
  return(
    <button className="modal-button" id="modal-sign-up-submit-button" onClick={this.submit}>Submit</button>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're creating a button with an id of 'submit-button'. You're searching for a button that doesn't exist. Try to enter the following:

```
document.getElementById('modal-sign-in-submit-button');
```

If you're looking for a framework that will allow you to identify elements on the DOM, I would recommend jQuery for dev purposes. Please note that you should try to avoid using jQuery as it is heavy and rather pointless.

I would also like to recommend that you try using lambda expressions or fat arrow functions for this.openModal & this.closeModal. This will allow you to keep the context of 'this' without the usage of .bind(). The obvious benefits are: improved code readability and the explicit binding of 'this'.

Here is an example:

```
openModal() => { this.setState({ open: true });
closeModal() => { this.setState({ open: false });
```

I hope that helps!